# AWS ECR Repository - How to copy images from one account and push to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I have two accounts - Account A and Account B.  In account A, I have a policy with a user from account B can interact with Account A. I have a repository in both accounts. Account B doesn't have a policy set ( Not sure if I need a policy for Account A to interact with it).

My question is how do I push ecr images from Account A into Account B. I would like a copy of Account A image into Account B. Is this possible.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is not a currently supported feature of ECR so you would need to perform the following steps to migrate from one account to another:

- `aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com` - Run this for the source account
- `docker pull $SOURCE_IMAGE:$VERSION` - Pull the latest tag down to your local
- `docker tag $SOURCE_IMAGE:$VERSION $TARGET_IMAGE:$VERSION` - [Tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) a new image based on the original source image
- `aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com` - Run this for the target account
- `docker push $TARGET_IMAGE:$VERSION` - [Push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) the docker image upto the target ECR account.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go!

Comment: You need to add pipe before de docker login command, e.g.: `aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing out. Adjusted the comment @Edenshaw

Comment: Note that while this is still the accepted answer (@paris), it is no longer accurate as AWS added this feature to ECR in December 2020.  For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671301/149428.

Comment: While CRR/CAR are great tools, this answer is still very relevant is you are interested in one-off deployments.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to move all repositry from particularly region to another account (Destination account) then use below script.

- It will list all repo from Account A
- Pull an image from an account A one by one
- Create Repo in Account B
- Tag image
- push image to account B

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-2"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-2"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH="123456.dkr.ecr.$DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION.amazonaws.com/"


REPO_LIST=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryUri' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))
REPO_NAME=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryName' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))


for repo_url in ${!REPO_LIST[@]}; do
        echo "star pulling image ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]} from Target account"
        docker pull ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}


        # Create repo in destination account, remove this line if already created
        aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]}
        docker tag   ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]} $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH/${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]} 
        docker push $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH/${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]} 
done
```

Make sure you already obtain login token for both account or add these command in the script.

```
        aws ecr get-login-password --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}
        # destination account login, make sure profile set for accoutn destination
        aws ecr get-login-password --region $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION --profile destination_account | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}
```

[aws-cli-cheatsheet](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet)

Or you can use one of them

- **AWS cross-region replication**
- **[Cross account replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/replication.html)**

[image: Cron account replication]

> Amazon ECR uses registry settings to configure features at the
> registry level. The private registry settings are configured
> separately for each Region. Currently, the only registry setting is
> the replication setting, which is used to configure cross-Region and
> cross-account replication of the images in your repositories

Comment: `docker pull ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}`
I'm confused: won't that just pull the 'latest' image from each repo? Isn't the question how to copy all images from A to B?

Comment: yeah it will copy all image with "latest" tags

Answer (score 5):

*cross Region/account Replication feature in AWS*

AWS has launched CRR (Cross Region Replication) and CAR (cross account replication)[Click here for more info](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/cross-region-replication-in-amazon-ecr-has-landed/)

Answer (score 0):

AWS ECR Cross Region/Account Replication Feature allows replication of **NEW** objects. If you had an existing repository and wanted to replicate all its objects to another region/account [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840220/20070706) is still the right one.

More Details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/replication.html#replication-considerations